# Submit HPC jobs to run java code

Tags: java, parallel-processing, openmpi, hpc

I have a java program and I need to run a large-scale test for performance testing. I have access to High-Performance Computing machines(Fujitsu) that are capable of compiling c/c++/fortron programs and submiting the code for distributed execution.

My objective is to spawn up to at least 30,000 instances of the java code as workers and spawn a lot of clients(how many should I spawn relative to workers?) to dispatch the jobs to the java workers. The Java code is given as it is for testing.

I look around and I found 
https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi-java-test

http://mpj-express.org

But both don't look to be under maintenance anymore.

I found Java binding for OpenMPI

https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=java

But I don't think it is what I'm looking for?

Any advice on the library and the number of clients i should spawn relative to the workers?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, 1) Yes, it is embarrassingly parallel. Actually, each jar job is listening to a port and they communicate through the port they listen to. Each of them is like a real computer in the real world, I'm trying to simulate them inside HPC and they are like workers who are there waiting and accept commands. When Clients issue commands to one of the java workers, After receiving a command, the java workers will interact with their peer workers to exchange information.

Comment: Think of it as a peer to peer program such as BitTorrent. The Java code is equivalent to  the Bittorrent program, the program code does not have internal looping that requires MPI. I think you are right, I don't need MPI(I just found out more by reading more), but how do I spawn 30K of them in a HPC?

Comment: I think this is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824683/redirect-output-of-my-java-program-under-qsub

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, thanks.